# Android JSch session closes after two commands

Tags: android, jsch

I'm attempting to run some commands over ssh from my app. I have a door unlocker and a script that takes lock or unlock.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            connectSSH();
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I setup the session in a separate thread as you cannot do networking in the main UI thread on android.

```
 private void connectSSH() 
{
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    try {
        session = jsch.getSession("door", "my server",22);

    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    session.setPassword("pass");
    session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    try {
        session.connect(40000);
        channel = session.openChannel("exec");
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

From here I just have button listeners:

```
 public void unlock(View view) {
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("python /home/door/doorUnlocker.py unlock");
    try {
        channel.connect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    channel.disconnect();
}

public void lock(View view) {
    ((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("python /home/door/doorUnlocker.py lock");
    try {
        channel.connect();
    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    channel.disconnect();
}
```

I can unlock, then lock the door but after that the session just closes so when it attempts to connect to the channel it throws an exception.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: I made a workaround that recreates the session and channel if it sees its down, this isn't what I would like I still don't see why it goes down in the first place. Even with this I still get odd behavior especially when reading the response from the channel.

Comment: Have you tried this outside Android ?